# What do `Drop As...` options of `Link Shell Extention` mean?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

After picking link source using [Link Shell Extention](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) as below snapshoot

[image]

We have the below options to drop. What are their meaning?

**For folder**

[image]

**For file**

[image]

Comment: havent u cross checked this one http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#junctions

Comment: @Vignesh4303 Would you please make it an answer? The link is not full of what we need - just about the hard link, symbolic link, junction.